# Как получить ID ссылки в ВКонтакте

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Есть ссылка `https://vk.com/XXXXXX?w=wall239752675_486` ее ID 486

Есть еще такая `https://vk.com/XXXXXX?w=wall-65888168_1449` ее ID 1449

Есть ли ВКонтакте способ получать ID этих ссылок?

Comment: это такая завуалированная реклама ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вас интересуют id записей на стене, вы можете использовать метод `wall.get`

Подробная информация находится в документации 
[vk.com/dev/wall.get](http://vk.com/dev/wall.get)

**UPD:**
Используйте регулярные выражения

```
<?php
  $link = 'vk.com/idхххххх?w=wall239752675_486';
  if (preg_match('#wall-?[0-9]+_([0-9]+)#', $link, $res)) {
    var_dump($res);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Нет мне нужно с такой вот ссылки https://vk.com/idхххххх?w=wall239752675_486  вытащить ее id 486 а далее уже по id я буду делать выборку на стене пользователя, дело в том что сама ссылка хранится в базе данных.

Comment: @Анатолий используйте регулярные выражения, обновил пост

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам, Вы мне очень помогли. А то 2 дня голову ламал, а решение оказывается такое простое.Еще раз благодарю Вас.

Comment: @AlexanderGrebenshikov, ваша регулярка берёт всё, что после =. А нужно то, что после _. Нужно использовать такую регулярку  `[^_]*$`.

Comment: @LEQADA, зависит от области применения, и валидности имеющихся данных, конечно. Но как минимум, в параметре w может быть не только пост, но и, например, wiki страница.

Comment: @AlexanderGrebenshikov, ТС вопрос поставил конкретный. Ему нужно то, что после _. Ну, если его всё устраивает в вашем ответе, то претензии уже не к вам, а к нему.

Comment: Все таки нужно Выбрать все цифры что идут после _
Как это сделать? А то с регулярными выражениями я вообще не дружу. PHP знаю на 2+

Comment: @Анатолий, ну выше скинули код регулярки, просто замените 
  `if (preg_match('#wall[0-9]+_([0-9]+)#', $link, $res)) {` на `if (preg_match('#[^_]*$#', $link, $res)) {
`